# Преобразование строки к определенному виду

Tags: java

Здравствуйте форумчане, что-то до меня никак не дойдет как реализовать функцию. 
Ее задача заключается в следующем:
Есть два массива:

```
char[] sentence = new char[]{'Н','Е',' ','П','О','Л','У','Ч','А','Е','Т','С','Я'};
char[] gamma = new char[]{'С','Л','О','В','О'};
```

В зависимости от длины sentence мне нужно получить массив следующего вида:

```
char[] result = new char[]{'C','Л','О','В','О','С','Л','О','В','О','С','Л','О'};
```

Есть у кого идеи как это лучше реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простенький пример, необходимо ввести дополнительный счетчик:

```
    char[] sentence = new char[]{'Н','Е',' ','П','О','Л','У','Ч','А','Е','Т','С','Я'};
    char[] gamma = new char[]{'С','Л','О','В','О'};

    char[] result = new char[sentence.length];
    int countForGamma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        result[i] = gamma[countForGamma];
        countForGamma++;
        if (countForGamma == gamma.length) {
            countForGamma = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь.